# What is the correct way to set up sw RAID1 so either drive boots?

Tags: centos, software-raid

I've set up a non-UEFI CentOS 6.6 "blank" install with `/boot` and `/` each in a separate RAID 1 (3 drives/1 spare). I removed one drive, rebooted, and let it sync to the spare. When I saw this was complete, I added a third drive, let it sync, and then removed a different drive. This time, I get only a flashing cursor booting from either of the remaining two drives. Do I need to copy my MBR to all three drives, or something else? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: In the initial question, I was getting kernel panics after removing a drive, but I hadn't given enough time for both RAID volumes to sync. I've updated the question.

/etc/fstab, /etc/mdadm.conf, /boot/grub/grub.conf:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Thu Mar  5 08:30:44 2015
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=875d9c47-8f70-4545-8d11-16264e0dfe01 /                       ext4    defaults                   1 1
UUID=a41ea1b5-6155-46b5-baac-395d5f9f06bc /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=67724b5c-3bf7-43c2-af68-d165a72c7919 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=6803812c-7478-4586-91bf-aca1d93b117a swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=2f7c37b5-8e2a-4acb-9310-8f1841338383 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
LABEL=BACKUP        /backup         xfs defaults    0 0
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
MAILADDR root
AUTO +imsm +1.x -all
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=abd0217f:a277c9ed:fe406fe9:fda616f3
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=e8bb6fca:e7b00a8d:1b9331b8:9dde9ce4
[root@localhost ~]# cat /boot/grub/grub.conf
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/md1
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0 
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=875d9c47-8f70-4545-8d11-16264e0dfe01 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_MD_UUID=e8bb6fca:e7b00a8d:1b9331b8:9dde9ce4 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64.img
title CentOS 6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)
root (hd0,0)
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=UUID=875d9c47-8f70-4545-8d11-16264e0dfe01 rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_MD_UUID=e8bb6fca:e7b00a8d:1b9331b8:9dde9ce4 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet
initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is KP?

Comment: @richard: "kernel panic", but this was my stupid fault (see note in question). I've re-phrased the question to reflect. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install grub to all 3 drives using `grub-install`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did this, but still cannot boot. I had no trouble booting to any drive when I used 3x2GB drives, as it was msdos/MBR. This time it's GPT. Is there something different I have to do with GPT to make it bootable vs. MBR? (Forgive ignorance if I got something wrong there).

Comment: Clarification: I believe I have to use GPT this time because the drives are 4TB.

Comment: @kiwisan, you need to have a 1 mb bios_grub partition or grub will complain loudly or fail to install.

Comment: I certainly had to do this, and I also THINK I had to copy the mbr from the original OS installed drive to the other two using dd (`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1`). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@psusi is correct that you need to install grub to all 3 drives, but you also need to check that the system will boot from the 2nd or 3rd drive if the first is missing/failed.

I also notice you have 3 swap partitions, presumably 1 on each drive. So your spare is not really spare since it's used as for swapping. As such, it's not clear that the system would continue running if a drive failed. The likelihood is that if would promptly panic and reboot - probably not what you want!

Normal practice would be to configure the swap partition as a RAID1 array as well since then the system will just carry on with degraded arrays while it rebuilds to the (now active) spare.

BTW, I assume you are just testing the rebuild capability, since, if the system runs for any time at all with a drive as a spare, then as soon as one of the active drives fail, the "spare" will be completely resync'd.

Comment: If I have a failed drive and I plug in a blank replacement, in my tests (with 3x2GB, all of this was working, see comment @psusi) I would boot to a failover drive, run  `sgdisk -R /dev/sd[dest] /dev/sd[source]` to copy the partitions (2x raid and 1xswap). After this is done, I add the new partitions to the RAID with `mdadm` and both arrays rebuild. I thought swap was it's own partition type (how can I have it as both swap and raid?). Thanks.

Comment: @kiwisan, there is no reason swap has to be on a partition tagged with the swap ID ( in fact linux doesn't care at all about partition type IDs ), so you simply `mkswap` and `swapon` the /dev/mdXX raid1 device instead of the partition on the disk.